# Adding Spacing Between Basic Table View Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have basic table view cells that I want to set some spacing between them.

[image]

I tried

```
cell.contentView.layoutMargins.top = 8
```

and

```
cell.layoutMargins.top = 8
```

but that didn't work. I know I can create a custom cell, but I want to know how I can add margins this way.

**EDIT:**

Then I changed the cell style to custom:

[image]

and added a view so I can set up some constraints to it

[image]

but the results still the same, no spacing between cells, and it kinda ignored the custom view, i guess because it needs a custom class for the cell, but I don't want to do that.

[image]

Comment: just create your cell that contains the cell view + extra space view (that it have same color as background), then it will look like spacing between cell

Comment: The easiest and shortest way for me was to add a custom view at the bottom

Answer (score 6):

You should not add spacing between cells themselves, but rather add a custom `containerView` to cell's `contentView` with a top and/or bottom constraints.

[image]

Comment: This sounds a good idea, but it gives an error that Container views can't be placed in a view that's repeated at run time. Then, I changed the cell configuration from Basic to Custom, I added a view within the Content View and played with constraints, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: @fullMoon Please add your layout to the question so that I can find the issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try it 
you can create header between two cell and add space

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 1 // Because we need to space between two cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    //Configure your cell

    let cel:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!
    cel.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.section] //please use section because we have only one row for all section
    return cel
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    return 15 // whatever you want space between two cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You achieve adding spacing between cells is to make numberOfSections = array.count and make each section contains only one row. And then define headerView and its height.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellSpacingHeight
    }
```

Comment: It is sort of a workaround, but don't do that. Table view sections are meant for another purpose. You'll find yourself in an awkward position when you follow this advise and at some point later really need to separate some cells into sections

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single section try interchanging the number of rows in section and the number of the sections in tableView. Then for spacing in between you can use delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, working with a `UITableViewCell`'s or its `contentView`'s `layoutMargins`  is error prone.  In my experience the `layoutMargins` of both the cell and the `contentView` get reset at several points during table reload. There are two workarounds:

1. Use a spacing cell.  For example, just create a transparent UITableViewCell subclass that has a specific height constraint set on the contentView.
2. Use a transparent `UITableViewCell` subclass, and add your own (possibly opaque) subview to the `contentView` and set the top/bottom constraints to 1/2 your desired spacing.  You can override `setHighlighted:animated` to control how the cell looks on selection.  This is the method I'm using in the screenshots.  It also works great for adding a margin on the left/right.

[image]
[image]